# How to load a DLL using Activator.CreateInstanceFrom?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, plugins, architecture

I want to develop AppDomain project so I want to load a DLL but the code below gives me an error:

> Could not load type 'test' from assembly 'ClassLibrary1,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

How to solve it?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain yenidomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("PluginDomain", null, null);

        ObjectHandle oh = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(
            yenidomain, @"S:\Source\Yusuf.Karatoprak\plugins\ClassLibrary1.dll","test", false,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
            null, new object[] { },
            null, null, null);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `test` the full name of your type? Add the full namespace!